# Retrofit - POST request with @Path and without parameters

Tags: android, rest, post, retrofit, retrofit2

The request to API as follows:

> POST /verify/phone/{userid}/
>
> Mandatory parameters: userid  (integer)
>
> Return: nothing

I receive `Bad Request` error all the time if I want to verify user with id 1 (for example):

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://dummyapi.com/verify/phone/1/}`

Posting the same request using Postman works well.

**Code**:

`@POST("/verify/phone/{userid}/")
 Call<String> postVerifyPhone(@Path("userid") int userId);`

```
public void postVerifyPhone(int userID){
    showProgressBar();

    RestClient.GitApiInterface service = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<String> call = service.postVerifyPhone(userID);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<String> response) {
            hideProgressBar();

            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                String result = response.body();
            } else {
                Log.d("Fail: ", response.body()); //everytime here with Bad Request
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using String as the return type since there's message returned when there're no user with requested ID in db.

**What could be a cause?**

Comment: can you able to see the response in the app which is coming from server??

Comment: No since `response.body()` is null

Comment: Do you have access to the REST API code or documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am calling below code for reading response data.

```
public void postVerifyPhone(int userID){
          RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                 .setEndpoint(Constants.URL).build();
          RetrofitApi retrofitApi = restAdapter.create(RetrofitApi.class);
          retrofitApi.postVerifyPhone(userID, new Callback<Response>() {
          @Override
          public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                    String line;
                    try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  String result = sb.toString();
//                System.out.println("res:" + result.toString());

            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });


}
```

below is postVerifyPhone() code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/verify/phone/")
    public void postVerifyPhone(@Field("userID") String userID, Callback<Response> resonse);
```

It is working fine for me.please check it once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right annotation is @PathParam, not @Path